# Trying to relate information theory basics and physics

Tags: permutations, information-theory

I am a layman interested in information, and wondered how far off this idea is:

Imagine 2 levels and 3 particles (in the physics sense, indistinguishable), and the different permutations:

- 1 arrange
  $$ L_{2} \hspace{1em} \_ \hspace{1em} \_ $$

$$ L_{1} \hspace{1em} x \hspace{1em} x\hspace{1em} x $$

- 6 eq. arrages
  $$ L_{2} \hspace{1em} \_ \hspace{1em} x $$

$$ L_{1} \hspace{1em} x \hspace{1em} \_ \hspace{1em} x $$

- 3 arranges

$$ L_{2} \hspace{1em} x \hspace{1em} x $$

$$ L_{1} \hspace{1em} x \hspace{1em} \_\hspace{1em} \_ $$

---

### Numbers

The total number of states is 10. Also can be get using the permutations formula.

### Entropy

The Shannon (or Boltzmann) formula would be

$$= − _1\,(_1) − _2\,(_2) − _3\,(_3)$$

$$= − 1/10\,_{2}(1/10) − 6/10\,_2(6/10) − 3/10\,_2(3/10)=1.3$$

This means that most of the time it is enough to specify a single bit of information to determine the state.

Is this idea correct or am I mislead?

Comment: You seem to be working with a probability distribution with values $1/13$, $6/13$, and $3/13$. But $1+6+3$ is $10$, not $13$, so this isn't really a probability distribution.

Comment: @AndreasBlass thank you, i fixed it. But is it the idea correct?

Comment: The first of your two formulas for $H$ has incorrect factors 2 and 3. The second formula is OK (except that $1.3$ is, of course, an approximation).

Comment: I wish more people would have help. I am just asking for some feedback. I understand now. So the result that 1.3 bits are on average necessary is correct (it yields 1.29..)? (I will fix the factors). Thank you @AndreasBlass